# Listening for external API changes Node JS

Tags: node.js, api, stream

I'm using a real time API that at any given time contains some data and is updated every minute. I want to store this data in my database so I can make some simple time series analysis.

What's the best way to create a node server that listens for changes in the external API and stores the data to my database when the data changes?

The code below extracts the API data correctly but I'm not sure how to set my server up for listening to changes in the API

```
https.get(url, (res) => {
    res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do a pooling request ....

Something like

```
setInterval(() => {
    //do the request
}, 1000);
```

Where 1000 = 1000ms = 1s , or every second.

**Be careful**, a API request is an I/O operation, so NodeJS makes it async. You'll need to control that.

Comment: This is perfect actually, I'll go with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using this one as solution

[agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda)